# What is the role of Ketu in different houses of Janam Kundli?

Tags: astrology, horary-astrology

I read that Ketu is considered to be the bringer of past life karma into present life. So if Ketu is in say the 7th house, it means the person did some bad karma in their previous marital life and hence have to work extra hard to nullify its effect in present life ? Or does it mean that the person has balanced all karma in that sector in previous life and hence no longer has any special desire in this sector of their life ?

Comment: Ketu is tail/end and usually associated with cutting, operations and with Moksha as well in its good state while its opposite Rahu with inflation, oblivion and bondage. When Ketu comes in 7th house, the real problem is not ketu but Rahu which will we be in the 1st house as both Rahu and Ketu are always diagonal opposite in a horoscope. Malefic Rahu in 1st house will inflate ego or mental confusion or mental problems or face problems for person as 1st house represents head, face and thinking of person. Ketu in 7th means problems in marriage as Rahu in 1st will anyway hamper thinking of him/her.